# Using both cook and serve pudding and instant pudding in pie

Tags: substitutions, pie, pudding

I have a layered Pudding Pie recipe that calls for Chocolate, Vanilla, and Butterscotch pudding. I have not been able to get the Butterscotch pudding in instant pudding (which is what the recipe calls for), only in cook and serve. Would it cause the milk in the other two to curdle when that layer is applied, and if so, how would I avoid that problem? I intend to let the pie set in the fridge overnight.

Comment: So your recipe has you prepare each pudding according to the package instructions, then layer the puddings together in a crust? Or is it more elaborate than that?

Comment: "So your recipe has you prepare each pudding according to the package instructions, then layer the puddings together in a crust?" Yes, pouring one layer, then preparing the next and pouring that layer, and repeat. The Butterscotch layer is the second layer.

Comment: You probably need to chill the cook and serve pudding until it's soft set, otherwise it will be too runny and it will end up getting mixed into the top layer. I don't think it would curdle the other puddings if you put it on hot, but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt it would make the milk curdle, but it may mix with the other layers if you pour it in while still hot. I would cook the layer with cook-and-serve pudding and let it cool in the pot until it's more spreadable than pourable. It should be just about room temperature by then, and then you can layer it on top of whatever layer it's supposed to be on without any worries. If the butterscotch is the first layer, you can pour it hot into the pie shell and wait until it's cooled before adding the other two layers.

Comment: Although the recipe called for it to be the middle layer, I decided to put it in as the first layer, put it in the fridge for 30 minutes, then did the instant layers.